# RedirectFactory already exists in context object. How to solve this problem in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

\Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\RedirectFactory already exists in context object. How to solve this problem in magento 2?

Comment: Did you write a custom module with a controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$context->getRedirectFactory();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have injected `\Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\RedirectFactory` this class which is already available in your injected class so it shows such an error

you can get the RedirectFactory using context object

```
$this->redirectFactory =  $context->getRedirectFactory();
```

and then you can use your redirectFactory as you were.

Answer (score 0):

You might have injected RedirectFactory in your controller class however redirectFactory method is already build in Context class and a controller's constructor must require this class. This class provides access to many functionality such as getRequest(),getResponse(), getUrl, getResultFactory() and getResultRedirectFactory().

Hence for redirect, you don't need to inject any other class in your constructor however you can achieve it wit below code -

```
$redirect = $context->getRedirectFactory();
```